# Customizing NSTableView rows background

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

How could I change the background of each row of a NSTableView?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation will tell you.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/)

If you want to set the background color differently for specific rows, columns, or row-column intersections, [be the table view's delegate and respond to `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRow:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:) by [setting the background color of the cell](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextFieldCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextFieldCell/setBackgroundColor:).